# See if value is null, if it is insert data SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to

- Create a new table if the table doesn't exist
- If it does, and there is **no** data in it ,insert some

Here is what I have so far:

```
--See if AuditActivities exists
IF OBJECT_ID('Audit') is not null
--here is where I need to see if either rows are null, if so, enter data
ELSE
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit]
(
AuditSys int,
Description nvarchar(50)
);
```

Comment: You can use a simple Count() statement to see if there are any rows, then use Inserts if the result is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Audit]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit]
    (
        AuditSys int,
        Description nvarchar(50)
    )
END


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Audit])
BEGIN
    --INSERT here
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select * from [Audit])
  begin    
  ...
  end
else
  begin
  ...
  end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be IF NOT EXISTS (select * from [audit])?

Comment: Right on, that would be cleaner.  And if you don't want to use exists you can check that the count(auditsys) > 0 as KingCronus mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Audit') is null
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit]
    (
    AuditSys int,
    Description nvarchar(50)
    )
END
ELSE 
   IF exists(select * from Audit)
   --insert some record
     INSERT INTO Audit(COL1,COL2,..)
     VALUES (VAL1,VAL2,...)
```